# Como puedo recoger dos registros con laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Hola gente no se exactamente como puedo recoger varios registros con el query de laravel, necesito exactamente recoger dos selects en dos variables distinas y en el mismo foreach, yo he intentado de la siguiente manera pero sin resultado

```
$selectProductosB = cliente::select('nombre','nif')->where('nombre', $cliente )->get();

foreach ($selectProductosB as $selectProductoB) {

    $selectProductoB =$selectProductoB->nombre;
    $selectProductoC =$selectProductoB->nif;


    }
```

Comment: No termino de entender la duda procura ser más claro por favor

Comment: lo he aclarado un poco, la cosa es que necesito recoger en dos variables dos registros, lo que no se es como puedo hacerlo en un mismo foreach

Comment: Puedes utilizar la relacion si estan en dos tablas diferentes si estan en una misma puedes usar las expresiones RAW https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo tienes que cambiar las variables dentro del foreach ya que selectProductoB ya lo estas usando como value dentro del bucle.

En $selectProductosB estas obteniendo todas las filas con las columnas 'nombre' y 'nif' de la tabla cliente.

```
$selectProductosB = cliente::select('nombre','nif')->where('nombre', $cliente )->get();
```

Dentro del foreach recorres cada fila y guardas en una variable el nombre del cliente y el nif. El problema es que se sobreescriben las variables entre si dentro del bucle, ya que si se trae la fila del cliente 1 y saca el nombre y el nif y los guarda en $nombre_cliente y $nif_cliente, cuando itere por el cliente 2 va a guardar su nombre y su nif en esas variables. Si quieres guardar todos los nombres y nif de la consulta tendras que hacerlo en un array.

```
foreach ($selectProductosB as $selectProductoB) {

    $nombre_cliente =$selectProductoB->nombre;
    $nif_cliente =$selectProductoB->nif;
}
```